# Close button in html

Tags: html, css, button

I am new to HTML and CSS. I'm trying to design an closable dialog box with an X button.

I arrive to see the X button in the dialog text upper bar, however, I can't close it. Every time I click the button, it stays where it is.

How could I solve this problem?

```css
.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-header" data-closable="slide-out-up">
  <button class="close" aria-label="Dismiss alert" type="button" data-close>
        <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-window-close">X</i></span>
      </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using javascript? If so, could you add it in?

Comment: Please see [ask] and revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: CSS and HTML aren't scripting languages. What do you expect to close the button? Normally the close button doesn't disappear anyway because it's inside the modal, which gets closed itself.

Comment: `data-closable="slide-out-up"` and `data-close` make it seem as if you are using some kind of library/framework. If that is the case, please provide which one and make it part of the [mcve]. If you just copied this code from somewhere ([??](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/close-button.html)) then you're out of luck. This doesn't work out of the box without the library/framework.

Comment: check out https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_modal.asp its simple and sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: Pure CSS solution https://codepen.io/felipefialho/pen/oEula

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result you want by using CSS :checked selector.

instead:

```
  <button class="close" aria-label="Dismiss alert" type="button" data-close>
    <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-window-close">X</i></span>
  </button>

.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

use:

```
  <input type="checkbox" class="close" aria-label="Dismiss alert" data-close>
    <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-window-close">X</i></span>
  </input>

.close:checked {
//when closed input checked run (e.g. change the display property of the menu you want to show):
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use JavaScript `onclick` event handler for the `<button>` element like this

```
onclick="document.getElementById('modalWindow').style.display='none';"
```

Where modalWindow is an id of you modal window. See an example bellow:

```css
/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="modalWindow">
  <div class="modal-header" data-closable="slide-out-up">
    <button class="close" aria-label="Dismiss alert" type="button" data-close onclick="document.getElementById('modalWindow').style.display='none';">
      <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-window-close">X</i></span>
    </button>
  </div> 
  <div>
  This is modal window text....
  </div>
</div>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById for pure JavaScript DOM handling